# Access the properties of comopnent inside item renderer

Tags: apache-flex

I have an Item Renderer having HBox. Now I want to add child in that HBox from my application file using addChild method. Could anybody please suggest me the way around for the same.
I am not able to access the properties of HBox inside the item renderer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do that - even if you get a reference to the instance of item renderer and make modifications to it (addChild or whatever), you'll loose it when the item renderers are recycled. And item renderers are frequently recycled - for example when you scroll the list. If the list has 100 items and only 10 are visible at a given time, only 11 or so instances of item renderers will be created. Those instances will be showed in a cycle - when you scroll, the data in them are updated using the `set data` method.

Override the `set data` method in the item renderer and do the stuff from there.

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh for reply, well on selection of some checkboxes  I want to add child in the HBox of the item renderer, so can i achieve that with this. I am newbie in flex so getting bit confused with this.

Comment: In this case then will I be needed to access the application collections? as in on selection of some checkboxes i want to add that no. of hbox in my selected rows... so here i'll need to access the array collection of those selected checkboxes in my main application right??